# .NET DLL attributed are not visible when exposed via WCF

Tags: c#, java, .net, wcf, dll

I am developing a WCF Service to wrap a set of DLL files developed in .NET.

This is done for me to access the service from a Java Client.

I have successfully done the deployment of the WCF and the services are working properly.

Also, in one of the service methods I return a type of an object which is part of the DLL file.

This object is visible in the client but I cannot see the data values within them. The Objects gets created.

I am not a .NET expert, hence need some background information as well as why it is not visible.

Comment: Just to discard things, can you confirm that the service works as expected when tested with SoapUI or any other standard webservice client?

Comment: Please give some idea about Object model... like entity structure & expected data & actual data

Comment: Posting as a comment, but could an answer! Are the values coming through as nulls, or are they not present at all. I once embedded a call to a WCF service into a .NET 2, old skool web application and I had to specify a boolean for each property to tell it that I was specifying values. It's an oddity and possibly not your issue, but I thought worth sharing. For more info - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeneos/archive/2007/02/05/solving-the-disappearing-data-issue-when-using-add-web-reference-or-wsdl-exe-with-wcf-services.aspx

Comment: The service works without any problem. I have created a sample service with some data types which I have defined within the application. it works without a problem. when it comes to exposing data objects which is inside the DLL file, the data is not NULL, but the values are not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attribute the object with the `DataContract` attribute and every property (!) that should be passed to the client with the `DataMember` attribute.

While I wrote above it needs to be a property, it could be it works with public variables also, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The Data objects which are not visible are within the DLL file. hence I cannot put the DataContract/DataMember values. The Object that I'm trying to access is in DLL>TestObject>public attribute:A. The TestObject gets visible, but not the attributes or the operations

Comment: Operations don't get visible by default, as not the object itself is transferred, but only the *data*. On the client side, only a stub is created which contains the data properties. So by default you can not transfer methods to the client, only properties. And those must be part of a `DataContract`. So I guess what you want simply does not work.

Comment: Does that mean that i have to create a set of wrappers at the Service level to wrap all objects of the DLL that i need to be transferred via WCF?

Comment: I would suppose so. Note that you still can not transfer *operations* (i.e. methods). Only *data*!

Comment: I think I may have to park it there and create the set of wrappers required. Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Pleasure. The equivalent of "Thanks a lot" is to upvote/accept the answer.